# read-minibuffer function input string with " Punctuation

Tags: emacs

I write emacs lisp code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(setq input (read-minibuffer "please input your name:") )
(message "%s" input)
```

and then I use this code to test standard input:

```
./test.el
please input your name:hello
hello
```

this is ok for the first test. But when I put string `hello,world` to standard input, it occurs error:

```
please input your name:hello,world
Trailing garbage following expression
```

And then I put string `"hello,world"` to standard input, it passed:

```
please input your name:"hello,world"
hello,world
```

Then I want to know, how should I do that can get the input string without `"`
punctuation. I just want to input `hello,world`, rather then `"hello,world"`.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `read-minibuffer` expects the user to input a Lisp object.  If you enter `hello`, it returns a symbol, and if you enter `"hello,world"`, it returns a string.

You probably want the function `read-from-minibuffer` instead. It returns what the user entered as a string, without trying to interpret it in any way.